# SQL INSERT INTO Table A value from Table B based on Inner Join or where condition

Tags: sql, insert

I need some help,

```
select 
    c.CityId, c.CityTitle, c.CountyID_fk, c.countytitle, 
    ct.CountyTitle, ct.CountyID 
from 
    tblCity C
inner join 
    tblCounty CT on ct.CountyTitle = c.CountyTitle
```

[This is the output of this query to show two tables tblCity and tblCounty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFOp0.png)

I need to insert `CountyID`s from `tblCounty` into the `tblCity` table for the column `CountyID_fk`.

I tried this:

```
insert into tblCity (CountyID_fk) 
    select 
        (select CountyID 
         from tblCounty C 
         inner join tblCity ct on ct.countytitle = c.CountyTitle)
```

But I get only this error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Any suggestions?

I tried the SQL query shown above, but I only get an error. I think I need to modify the query a bit.

Comment: Do you want to **insert** new rows with the `CountyID` into your table - or did you mean to **update** existing rows in your table with the `CountyID` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
insert into 
  tblCity (CountyID_fk) 
select 
  CountyID 
from 
  tblCounty C 
inner join 
  tblCity ct 
on 
  ct.countytitle = c.CountyTitle
```

Following on from Jeremys comment below...

The top part here:

```
insert into 
  tblCity (CountyID_fk)
```

Is the standard T-SQL INSERT command, whereby you specify the Table you wish to insert into and a list of the attributes(column values) you would like to insert.  This is a comma separated list of the form:

```
(<column 1>,<column 2>,...,<Column n>)
```

Where n = total columns you want to insert.

The next part is the part where you provide the data that you want to insert.  In a standard INSERT command you would normally provide the keyword VALUES, followed by a list of tuples (rows), with each row matching the list of columns above.  The   So, in your example, a "standard" SQL INSERT would look like:

```
INSERT INTO 
  tblCity (CountyID_fk) 
VALUES
  (<CountryID_fk value>);
```

Now, because the INSERT command expects a set of data, i.e a number of rows to insert, the number of rows can be generated in a number of different ways.

In my suggested solution, the number of rows are generated by a separate SQL command, shown here:

```
    select 
      CountyID 
    from 
      tblCounty C 
    inner join 
      tblCity ct 
    on 
      ct.countytitle = c.CountyTitle
```

This SELECT statement will (inner) join the tables tblCountry and tblCity on the countrytitle attribute and will return a set of rows (probably just one) containing the CountyID (or an empty row if the (inner) join fails).

So, that is why you can combine the INSERT command with a SELECT to insert data into a table.

I hope this kind of explains my suggested solution.

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

You were nearly correct but you can not select and then (select with out doing a top 1